# Null value was assigned to a property of primitive type while hibernate query execution?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

i have below code snippet in dao

```
 String GET_CUSTOMER="SELECT * from customer where custName=:custName"
  Session session = getHibernateUtil().getSession();
  SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(GET_CUSTOMER);

    query.setParameter("custName", custName);
    query.setResultTransformer(Transformers
        .aliasToBean(Customer.class));

    Customer custData = (Customer) query
        .uniqueResult();//line
```

Customer table  has some int columns for which  some values as null. Now at line1 i get error
Null value was assigned to a property of primitive type setter of Customer.Address

Is there a way in hibernate/query/Transformer to convert the null values to 0 automatically?
I have just mentioned one table i.e customer but there are various joined table which contains int value as null in various columns so i do
not want to handle in query for each table.

**UPDATE:-** Customer is not Hibernate entity. It pojo with instance fields of int type

Comment: have you created mapping files for customer table....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Customer table has some int columns for which some values as null.

In that case I'd recommend making them `Integer` fields instead. While you *could* probably get Hibernate to coalesce `NULL` to `0` (although possibly not in an easy global manner), it's not really mapping your data effectively - why would you want to lose information like that?

Comment: you mean to say that make fields in customer class as Integer instead of int.Right?

Comment: Jon Thanks is there a way we can do it thru ResultTransformer where i can define rule if value is null and field is of type int, then set it as 0. The reason is  customer is a legacy class and i wan to take it last resort

Comment: @emilly do you find any solution?

Comment: yes it works. update to primative type

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about Hibernate transformers, but I have a different idea. Can you change the database? You could make the column not nullable and with default value 0. That way all possible values you can store in the database can be mapped to the int primitive.